# Release configuration build, debug doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build-process

I'm developing an AutoCad plugin (MFC dll), I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C++.
Until now I was building the project with release configuration (both 32 and 64 bits), with no problems (I've test the plugin inside AutoCad).
But now that I want to debug a function with Visual Studio 2010 just changed the configuration to Debug and the build doesn't succeeded.

The output from build process:

```
------ Build started: Project: SAM, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
Build started 26/01/2012 11:36:32.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "x64\Debug\SAM.unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  stdafx.cpp
  Note: including file: c:\vs2010_workspace\s\sam\stdafx.h
  Note: including file:  c:\vs2010_workspace\s\sam\targetver.h
  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\SDKDDKVer.h
  Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h
  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h
  Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h
  Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sal.h
  Note: including file:       c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(27): error C2448: 'message' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vadefs.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vadefs.h(121): error C2065: 'va_list' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\vadefs.h(121): error C2059: syntax error : ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(486): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'time_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(550): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'uintptr_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1961): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'locinfo'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1961): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1961): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1962): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mbcinfo'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1962): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1962): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1980): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'lc_id'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1980): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(1980): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(52): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(52): error C2065: 'new_handler' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(52): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_NewHandler'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(52): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(52): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(52): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(58): error C2039: 'new_handler' : is not a member of 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\new.h(58): error C2873: 'new_handler' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
  Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxver_.h
  Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h
  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winsdkver.h
  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\windows.h
  Note: including file:       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\excpt.h
  Note: including file:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
  Note: including file:       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdarg.h
  Note: including file:       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\windef.h
  Note: including file:        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h
  Note: including file:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h
  Note: including file:          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(57): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(59): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(93): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(95): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(97): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(99): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(101): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(103): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(105): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(107): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(109): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(111): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(113): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(115): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(119): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(121): error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_locale_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(135): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(135): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(135): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(135): error C2491: 'iswalpha' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(135): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(136): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(136): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(136): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(136): error C2491: '_iswalpha_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(136): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(137): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(137): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(137): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(137): error C2491: 'iswupper' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(137): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(138): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(138): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(138): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(138): error C2491: '_iswupper_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(138): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(139): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(139): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(139): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(139): error C2491: 'iswlower' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(139): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(140): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(140): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(140): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(140): error C2491: '_iswlower_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(140): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(141): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(141): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(141): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(141): error C2491: 'iswdigit' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(141): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(142): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(142): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(142): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(142): error C2491: '_iswdigit_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(142): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(143): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(143): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(143): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(143): error C2491: 'iswxdigit' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(143): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(144): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(144): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(144): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(144): error C2491: '_iswxdigit_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(144): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(145): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(145): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(145): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(145): error C2491: 'iswspace' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(145): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(146): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(146): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(146): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(146): error C2491: '_iswspace_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(146): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(147): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(147): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(147): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(147): error C2491: 'iswpunct' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(147): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(148): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(148): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(148): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(148): error C2491: '_iswpunct_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(148): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(149): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(149): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(149): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(149): error C2491: 'iswalnum' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(149): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(150): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(150): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(150): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(150): error C2491: '_iswalnum_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(150): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(151): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(151): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(151): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(151): error C2491: 'iswprint' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(151): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(152): error C2065: 'wint_t' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(152): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_C'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(152): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(152): error C2491: '_iswprint_l' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h(152): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation

Build FAILED.
```

PS.: I'm not an expert developing whit c++ (I came from Java), I've started just a week ago.

### EDIT:

I've commented the piece of code below, and i was able to build. The code was on stdafx.h, and I have no clue of what it mean, someone could explain it to me?

```
#if defined(_DEBUG) && !defined(_FULLDEBUG_)
#define _DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#undef _DEBUG
#pragma
message (" Compiling MFC header files in release mode.")
#endif
```

Comment: Looks like you have some things in your code that don't belong.  A bit difficult to tell though without actually seeing your code.

Comment: Even though the dll builded with release config works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your project properties for Debug and for Release configuration and see if you are missing something. I would start with Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Comment: Well I agree with MGZero, it's really hard to help you without seeing your code... dependencies was first idea that came up to my mind. Try to find references of `_DEBUG` flag in your code.

Comment: Indeed the problem was with the _DEBUG flag. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a year late, but #pragma and message should be on the same line. Someone probably hit the enter key accidentally. This is why it works in release mode but not debug; _DEBUG is not defined in release configuration.

Visual Studio 2010 has a habit of giving you some weird error messages that should otherwise be straightforward parsing problems.